# client_secret not available in client_secret.json

Tags: java, android, google-drive-api

i am trying the command line demo application of google drive available at [here](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/source/browse?repo=samples#hg/drive-cmdline-sample). i have followed all the steps for creating a new project in google api console, and then downloaded **client_secret.json** file. after importing and running the project i got the **nullpointer exception**. after few hours of research i realize that exeption occurs because there is no client_secret available in client_secret.json file.

here is the image of my client_secret.json that i've downloaded. in which **client_secret** field is missing.

[image]

and i got the exception at

[image]

can someone please help me what mistake i've done here. from where do i get the client_secret. any help will be appreciated. thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try following the Java quickstart sample in the Google Drive SDK documentation to build a command-line Java app that uploads a file to Drive:

https://developers.google.com/drive/quickstart-java

Comment: Thnaks a lot for guiding me. the mistake was, i was creating and using  the client_secret.json for installed android application in java application. and moreover that quickstart for android helps me to run my first android demo application.