# How do I use the clients_secret json with connecting to Google Drive api Android

Tags: android, json, google-drive-api

I downloaded the clients_secret json from the API console. I have seen that I may need it from here: [client_secret not available in client_secret.json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14981772/client-secret-not-available-in-client-secret-json)

I am not sure how I should integrate it into my Android app, or what it's exactly for.

For one of my apps, I have gotten a 403 Forbidden error, when I followed an example.

Insight would be helpful with explanation.

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to learn how to correctly authorize your Android app to use the Drive API, then the quickstart guide is probably the way to go:

https://developers.google.com/drive/quickstart-android

Comment: how does the correlate with the client_secret json?

Comment: why do you need to use client_secrets.json when the Android authorization uses the package name/fingerprint hash as credentials instead of client id/client secret?

Comment: i want so use the default google account on the device. I was able to download the client_secret json, i thought it was gonna be able to use it for something. Granted that I know that Android needs to authenticate, and that the user needs to authenticate the app using drive. Just trying to figure out new ways to do things

Comment: the quickstart guide explains how to authenticate using a google account on the device. It pops up the account chooser dialog and then performs authorization in order to upload files to Drive

Comment: I've used that... modified it to try to work with a different application and had trouble uploading and downloading, one was with a json 403 error. Are there any other drive examples out there? that aren't the quickstart guide?

Comment: i like how the link says "examples", and there is just one... are there any more Android examples?

Comment: There's one example in multiple languages, I'm not aware of more Android-specific samples